# What beetle is this?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

I've found it in my kitchen. It seems to be that he flew through the window from the street.

The country is Russia.

[image: Unknown flyting beetle. Top side]
[image: Unknown flyting beetle. Bottom side]

Comment: What size was this specimen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **Mealworm beetle**, *Tenebrio molitor*, a species of darkling beetle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealworm

[image: Tenebrio molitor]

Thank you @terdon for help!

Answer (score 4):

I am not an entomologist, I just happen to have worked on the genome of the red flour beetle, *Tribolium castaneum* and this looks very similar. A quick [wikipedia search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_flour_beetle) turned up the amusingly named "confused flour beetle", *Tribolium confusa*, which looks almost exactly like what you have photographed:

[image]

So, I would *guess* (I stress that I don't really know) that this is some sort of Tribolium species and, by now, is thoroughly confused even if it was not to begin with.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've just read about this on Wikipedia and found that this is a Mealworm —  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealworm — a bigger version of a Tribolium.

Comment: @SunnyRebornPony well done! Could you please post that as an answer and accept it? The species name is mealworm beetle, _Tenebrio molitor_, mealworms are the larval (apparently edible!) stage.